# Две среды разработки одном компьютере

Tags: ide, c++

Можно ли на одном и том же компьютере пользоваться разными IDE, к примеру, wxDev-C++ и Visual C++? Не возникнут какие-то конфликтные ситуации?

Answer (score 1):

Да, можно.
Но по умолчанию (через оболочку даблкликом или пунктом "открыть") все открываться будет в последней установленной.
Иначе - нужно править ассоциации файлов.
Это в случае, если оболочки для одного языка. Если для разных, то и проблем с ассоциациями файлов быть не должно.
Единственное, что не нужно мешать разные версии одной оболочки. Например, MS VS'98 + MS VS.NET уживаются, а вот VS .NET 2001 и VS .NET 2005 - уже нет :-(

Comment: Спасибо, друзья!

Answer (score 0):

Да, можно, да, возникнут - нельзя двум IDE сделать ассоциации с одним файлом, но можно добавить в меню мыши открытие второй. Я бы не рекомендовал связываться с wxDev-C++: уж лучше тогда Notepad++ и консольный компилятор к нему прикрутить. И зачем он, если есть бесплатная студия, которая сделана для людей, а не от нечего делать.